# Is it possible to be hooked to lifetime events, similar to Autofac's OnActivating or OnActivated

Tags: java, dagger-2, dagger

I have Dagger component, which is created using several modules. Some modules are required by application, but some other modules are optional. In first module, a service is bound:

```
@Singleton
@Binds
abstract IService serviceBind(Service service);
```

In second, optional module, a lot of optional services are bound. I would like to use these optional services from second module (optional module) to perform some operations on service from first module. I do not want to have these optional services to be injected directly into service from first module, because I do not want class coupling, there may be a lot of optional services, I want to deal with them using reflection. Also, it is impossible to have all optional modules implementing common interface.

It would be very convenient if there was in Dagger a possibility to attach to instance lifetime event, like in Autofac (https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html). For example, I would use the following code:

```
// PSEUDOCODE!
@OnActivated
void serviceOnActivated(IService service, IServiceOptonal1 s1, IServiceOptonal2 s2){
   service.register(s1);
   service.register(s2);
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this in Dagger?